# ResultSet: reducing amount of time table is read-locked

Tags: java, resultset

I'm using a quite straightforward setup to generate a CSV file from a SELECT query. How do I reduce (or at least control) the time window where the query locks the database for reads?

Here's a typical example:

```
private List<String[]> getData(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    final List<String[]> res = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    int i = 0;
    int stride = 10;
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (++i % stride == 0) {
            System.out.println("Row " + i);
        }
        if (i >= stride * 10) {
            stride = stride * 10;
        }
        res.add(getRow(rs));
    }
    System.out.println("*** Total " + i + " rows");
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JDBC Transaction Isolation levels](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop71.html)

[Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)